# Limit recursion with one deepest loop and assign exact id to all elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

It is necessary to order the elements from the mixed order. Ordering is done using the recursion method.
Two conditions must be met that while are not implemented in the code:

- recursion should capture only the longest chain. Other chains should not be outputed
- an element with `STATUS '0'` (logically - the very first element in the chain) should not be displayed
- but its `id-3` value must be assigned to all other subsequent elements (with `STATUS='1'`in chain (as an additional "common-id" field).

**1-source**

```
<root>

  <object id-1="aaaa" parent-id="bbbb" id-3="COMMON-ID-1"  STATUS="0" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>
  <object id-1="1111" parent-id="2222" id-3="COMMON-ID-2"  STATUS="0" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>

  <object id-1="bbbb" parent-id="cccc" id-3="value"        STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>
  <object id-1="2222" parent-id="3333" id-3="value"        STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>
  <object id-1="cccc" parent-id="dddd" id-3="value"        STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>
  <object id-1="3333" parent-id="4444" id-3="value"        STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>
  <object id-1="dddd" parent-id="eeee" id-3="value"        STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>
  <object id-1="4444" parent-id="5555" id-3="value"        STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value"/>

</root>
```

**2- present XSLT** 
(produces all recursions, while only one is needed, a common ID is not assigned)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="by-id" match="object" use="@id-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="object" mode="ancestors">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

      <xsl:attribute name="COMMON-ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id-3[@STATUS='0']"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by-id', @parent-id)" mode="ancestors"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/object[@STATUS='1']" mode="ancestors"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3-output

```
<root>

  <object id-1="bbbb" id-2="cccc" id-3="value" STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1"/> <!-- chain 1-->
  <object id-1="cccc" id-2="dddd" id-3="value" STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1"/>
  <object id-1="dddd" id-2="eeee" id-3="value" STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1"/>

  <object id-1="2222" id-2="3333" id-3="value"  STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2"/>  <!-- chain 1-->
  <object id-1="3333" id-2="4444" id-3="value"  STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2"/>
  <object id-1="4444" id-2="5555" id-3="value"  STATUS="1" add-1="value" add-2="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2"/>

</root>
```

Comment: This is difficult (and time-consuming) to follow. I suggest you simplify the example to concentrate on a single problem. In general, it is not possible to "limit recursion to capture only the longest chain" when recursion is required to produce the chains. You need to generate all the chains first, then select the longest one (or ones, in case of a tie?).

Comment: So its better to reformulate a new one. Only how to choose the longest one chain? And separately about common-id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only how to choose the longest one chain?

Consider the following **much simplified** example.

**IMPORTANT**
In this example it is assumed that a parent `object` can have at most one child `object`. This allows us to begin the recursion with ancestor objects (objects that do not have a parent) and work downwards. Otherwise we would have to create a separate chain for every leaf object (an object that does not have any child objects) and recurse upwards from there.

**XML**

```
<root>
    <object id="a"/>
    <object id="b"/>
    <object id="c"/>
    <object id="aa" parent-id="a"/>
    <object id="bb" parent-id="b"/>
    <object id="cc" parent-id="c"/>
    <object id="aaa" parent-id="aa"/>
    <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb"/>
    <object id="ccc" parent-id="cc"/>
    <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb"/>
    <object id="cccc" parent-id="ccc"/>
    <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0 (+ node-set function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="object" use="@parent-id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- generate chains -->
    <xsl:variable name="chains">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="object[not(@parent-id)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- find the longest chain -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($chains)/object">
        <xsl:sort select="count(descendant::object)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() =1 ">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After the first pass, the `$chains` variable will contain:

```
<object id="a">
  <object id="aa" parent-id="a">
    <object id="aaa" parent-id="aa"/>
  </object>
</object>
<object id="b">
  <object id="bb" parent-id="b">
    <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb">
      <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb">
        <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb"/>
      </object>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>
<object id="c">
  <object id="cc" parent-id="c">
    <object id="ccc" parent-id="cc">
      <object id="cccc" parent-id="ccc"/>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>
```

After sorting the chains by their length (i.e. the count of descendant objects) and selecting the longest one we will get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object id="b">
  <object id="bb" parent-id="b">
    <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb">
      <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb">
        <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb"/>
      </object>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>
```

---

Hint: with recursion working downwards, it is very easy to use a *template parameter* to pass a common value from the ancestor to all its descendants.

Comment: thanks again! At last have time to carefully study your answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a change to your root template.  Your other templates stay the same. Hopefully, this will help.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="chains">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/object[@STATUS='1']" mode="ancestors"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="chainList" select="exslt:node-set($chains)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="objects">
      <xsl:for-each select="$chainList/object">
        <element>
          <position>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
          </position>
          <numberOfObjects>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(.//object)+1"/>
          </numberOfObjects>
        </element>       
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="objectList" select="exslt:node-set($objects)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="sortedObjects">
      <xsl:for-each select="$objectList/element">
        <xsl:sort select="numberOfObjects" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="sortedObjectList" select="exslt:node-set($sortedObjects)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="maxObjects" select="$sortedObjectList/element[1]/numberOfObjects"/>

    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="$objectList/element[numberOfObjects = $maxObjects]">
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="position"/>

        <xsl:copy-of select="$chainList/object[number($position)]"/>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks again. At last have time to carefully study your answer

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HR/1

I applied your code, restoring part of mine. Brilliant, it works as it should. The only point that remains is the COMMON-ID, as shown in the question. How difficult would it be to add some lines of code to solve this last option?