# Adding common attribute to all chains in recursion

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

*A follow-up question to: [Limit recursion with one deepest loop and assign exact id to all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872469/limit-recursion-with-one-deepest-loop-and-assign-exact-id-to-all-elements)*

This code collects recursion.
It is necessary that at the same time all recursion elements receive a `COMMON-ID` attribute with the value from the first element of the chain. This first element has also an attribue `STATUS="0"`. Other elements have `STATUS="1"` (for solution it may be useful).

**1-source**

```
<root>
  <object id="a" id-3="COMMON-ID-1" STATUS="0"/>
  <object id="b" id-3="COMMON-ID-2" STATUS="0"/>
  <object id="c" id-3="COMMON-ID-3" STATUS="0"/>

  <object id="aa" parent-id="a" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="bb" parent-id="b" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="cc" parent-id="c" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="aaa" parent-id="aa" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="ccc" parent-id="cc" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="cccc" parent-id="ccc" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
  <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb" id-3="value" STATUS="1"/>
</root>
```

2-present XSLT (do not assign `COMMON-ID`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="object" use="@parent-id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- generate chains -->
    <xsl:variable name="chains">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="object[not(@parent-id)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- find the longest chain -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($chains)/object">
        <xsl:sort select="count(descendant::object)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3-desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object id="b" id-3="COMMON-ID-1" STATUS="0" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2">
  <object id="bb" parent-id="b" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2>
    <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2>
      <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2>
        <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2/>
      </object>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>
<object id="c"  id-3="COMMON-ID-3" STATUS="0" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3">
  <object id="cc" parent-id="c" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3">
    <object id="ccc" parent-id="cc" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3">
      <object id="cccc" parent-id="ccc" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3"/>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>
<object id="a" id-3="COMMON-ID-1" STATUS="0" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1">
  <object id="aa" parent-id="a" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1">
    <object id="aaa" parent-id="aa" id-3="COMMON-ID-1" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1"/>
  </object>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 2nd template to:

```
<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:param name="common-id" select="@id-3"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="COMMON-ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="$common-id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @id)">
            <xsl:with-param name="common-id" select="$common-id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: potentially, such a result can be outputed in a "flat" not a "nested" form? (like in the  original source)

Comment: Yes, if you place the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction outside the `xsl:copy` block. And you will also want to add a root element in the other template, if you want to get a well-formed XML document instead of an XML fragment.

Comment: Made it. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepJ/1

Also tried to apply "path" attribute as is directly        `<xsl:attribute name="path"> <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1/1"/> </xsl:attribute>` Got it from the last request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076622/recursion-auto-incrementation-for-all-depth-level-elements-and-keeping-heredit. Doesn't work properly. Is it easy to modify code to get it working right, or better make a new question?

Comment: It works fine for me: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsL If you need additional features, post a new question. -- Note that constructing a "path" like the one you show would be easy to accomplish by passing another parameter to which each level appends its `position()` value.