# (Recursion-2) Auto-incrementation for all depth level elements and keeping heredity path

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

*Note This is a continuation of two other questions: [Limit recursion with one deepest loop and assign exact id to all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872469/limit-recursion-with-one-deepest-loop-and-assign-exact-id-to-all-elements) and [Adding common attribute to all chains in recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981902/adding-common-attribute-to-all-chains-in-recursion)*

*But, in the statement of the problem, the question is identical to the following: [(Recursion) auto-incrementation for all depth level elements and keeping heredity path in chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076622/recursion-auto-incrementation-for-all-depth-level-elements-and-keeping-heredit)*

So the wording of the present question remains the same, only in relation to the realities of the new XSLT code which is different.

- auto-incrementation for all depth level elements and keeping heredity path in chain
- (for example) 3 lvl depth recursion, for example it would look like "1/1/1" or "1/1/2" - if there is a sibling on a third level

**1-source**

```
<root>
  <object id="a" id-3="COMMON-ID-1"/>
  <object id="b" id-3="COMMON-ID-2"/>
  <object id="c" id-3="COMMON-ID-3"/>

  <object id="aa" parent-id="a" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="bb" parent-id="b" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="cc" parent-id="c" id-3="value"/>


  <object id="aaa" parent-id="aa" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="aaaa" parent-id="aa" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="ccc" parent-id="cc" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="cccc" parent-id="ccc" id-3="value"/>
  <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb" id-3="value"/>
</root>
```

2-XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="child" match="object" use="@parent-id" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- generate chains -->
    <xsl:variable name="chains">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="object[not(@parent-id)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- find the longest chain -->
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($chains)/object">
        <xsl:sort select="count(descendant::object)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:param name="common-id" select="@id-3"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="COMMON-ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="$common-id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @id)">
      <xsl:with-param name="common-id" select="$common-id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3-output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <object id="a" id-3="COMMON-ID-1" STATUS="0" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1" path="1"/>
  <object id="aa" parent-id="a" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1" path="1/1"/>
  <object id="aaa" parent-id="aa" id-3="value" STATUS="1" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-1" path="1/1/1"/>

  <object id="b" id-3="COMMON-ID-2" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2" path="2"/>
  <object id="bb" parent-id="b" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2" path="2/1"/>
  <object id="bbb" parent-id="bb" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2" path="2/1/1"/>
  <object id="bbbb" parent-id="bbb" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2" path="2/1/1/1"/>
  <object id="bbbbb" parent-id="bbbb" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-2" path="2/1/1/1/1"/>

  <object id="c" id-3="COMMON-ID-3" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3" path="3"/>
  <object id="cc" parent-id="c" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3" path="3/1"/>
  <object id="ccc" parent-id="cc" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3" path="3/1/1"/>
  <object id="cccc" parent-id="ccc" id-3="value" COMMON-ID="COMMON-ID-3" path="3/1/1/1"/>
</root>
```

Comment: I cannot understand why you need to look for the longest chain, when you want to output **all** `object` nodes present in the input. You're not even looking for the longest chain: your test is `<xsl:if test="position()">` which any node will pass, instead of the original `<xsl:if test="position()=1">`.

Comment: Yes you are right. It based on the code where the longest chain is initially calculated. Here in this case, it is not essential; the longest, or all chains will be assembled. It is important that any of the chains built according to your algorithm would get a "path". One or more chains is not so important. It seems to me that the solution will work equally with both cases. But if it confuses, I can return the condition of `position()=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will produce an output that is very close to the one you want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="object" use="@parent-id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="object[not(@parent-id)]"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:param name="common-id" select="@id-3"/>
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-path" select="concat($path, '/', position())"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="COMMON-ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="$common-id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="path">
            <xsl:value-of select="$new-path"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @id)">
        <xsl:with-param name="common-id" select="$common-id"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$new-path"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

AFAICT, the only difference is that all paths start with the `/` character. If that's a problem, you can do:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="path">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($new-path, 2)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

instead.